# Dynamic doctrine database connection

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, sqlsrv

I have a project of an monitoring application under symfony 5.

Currently I've done most of the work working with a single database containing logs from another application. What I'm looking to do now is to be able to connect dynamically to a database (MSSQL).
For the moment the connection to the database is done via the file "doctrine.yaml".

Doctrine.yaml

```
 doctrine:
  dbal:
   default_connection: default
    connections:
     default:
       driver: pdo_sqlsrv
       host: 192.168.1.33
       port: null
       dbname: 'job'
       user: 'sa'
       password: 'Lasernet@2020'
       charset: utf8mb4

   orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
     default:
       connection: default
       mappings:
        Main:
         is_bundle: false
         type: annotation
         dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main"
         prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
         alias: default
```

I did this for the dynamic connection

DynamicConnection.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine;


class DynamicConnection {


    public function __construct($dbname,$user,$password,$host,$driver,$port)
    {
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->driver = $driver;
        $this->port = $port;

    }

    public function changeDatabase(){



        $connectionParams = array(
            'dbname' => $this->dbname,
            'user' => $this->user,
            'password' => $this->password,
            'host' => $this->host,
            'driver' => $this->driver,
            'port' => $this->port
        );

        $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams);
    
        if($conn){
            return $conn;
        }else{
            return "no";
        }

    }


    public function getParams()
    {
        $connectionParams = array(
            'driver' => $this->driver,
            'host' => $this->host,
            'port' => $this->port,
            'dbname' => $this->dbname,
            'user' => $this->user,
            'password' => $this->password,
            'charset' => "utf8mb4",
            'driverOptions' => [],
            'defaultTableOptions' => []
        );

        return $connectionParams;
    }

}
```

And in my Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/testconnection", name="test_connect")
 */
public function testConnection(){


    $dbname = "job";
    $user = "sa";
    $password = "Lasernet@2020";
    $host = "192.168.1.34";
    $driver = "pdo_sqlsrv";
    $port = null;

    $connection = new DynamicConnection($dbname,$user,$password,$host,$driver,$port);
    $params = $connection->getParams();


    $newEm = EntityManager::create($params,$this->em->getConfiguration(), $this->em->getEventManager());


    $job = $newEm->getRepository(Job::class)->findAll();
    dd($job);
        
}
```

The problem is that the findAll() returns all the records of the database "192.168.1.33" not the one of "192.168.1.34" which behaves a different number of records.

Is there another way to connect dynamically to the database or to modify the "doctrine.yaml" file directly using JS for example, but I don't think this is the best solution.

If someone has a solution to my problem to make my findAll() return the info from the 192 database
.168.1.34

Small precision the two databases have the same structure of tables, fields, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a very similar issue recently. The solution that worked for me was a wrapper class.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DBAL;

use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;

final class MultiDbConnectionWrapper extends Connection
{
    public function __construct(
        array $params,
        Driver $driver,
        ?Configuration $config = null,
        ?EventManager $eventManager = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($params, $driver, $config, $eventManager);
    }

    public function selectDatabase(string $dbName): void
    {
        if ($this->isConnected()) {
            $this->close();
        }

        $params = $this->getParams();
        $params['dbname'] = $dbName;
        parent::__construct($params, $this->_driver, $this->_config, $this->_eventManager);
    }
}
```

If you want to change a db host, change `$params['host'] = 'XX.XX.XXX.XXX';`

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        wrapper_class: App\DBAL\MultiDbConnectionWrapper
```

```php
class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $em;
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    public function add(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $connection = $this->em->getConnection();
        if(!$connection instanceof MultiDbConnectionWrapper) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Wrong connection');
        }

        $databaseName = 'some_db_name';
        $connection->selectDatabase($databaseName);
```

You can find full implementation [in this repo](https://github.com/karol-dabrowski/symfony_dynamic_db).

Comment: Is there maybe an updated version of this, which does not use "internal" methods ? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Also you could want to see**

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-bundle/en/latest/middlewares.html

PreventRootConnectionMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Middleware;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Middleware;

class PreventRootConnectionMiddleware implements Middleware
{
    public function wrap(Driver $driver): Driver
    {
        return new PreventRootConnectionDriver($driver);
    }
}
```

PreventRootConnectionDriver.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Middleware;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Middleware\AbstractDriverMiddleware;
use SensitiveParameter;

final class PreventRootConnectionDriver extends AbstractDriverMiddleware
{
    public function connect(array $params): Connection
    {
        if (isset($params['user']) && $params['user'] === 'root') {
            throw new \LogicException('Connecting to the database with the root user is not allowed.');
        }

        return parent::connect($params);
    }
}
```